# Simple conditional on scanned input

Tags: java, string-comparison

I've written a simple program to check if the input is the letter O or not.  For some reason, even when I type the letter O, the program outputs that the input is not the letter O.  I have used the Eclipse debugger to ensure that the input variable actually equals "O".

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class scannerTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Give your input. I will tell you if your input is 'O' or not");
    String input = scan.next();
    if (input == "O"){
        System.out.println("Your input was 'O'");
        }
    else {
        System.out.println("Your input was not 'O'");
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `equals` method instead of the `==` operator, like this:

```
if(input.equals("O"))
```

Using `==` compares the memory address of the string objects instead of their values so in order for `==` to return `true` you would have to be comparing the same String object.

Comment: Ah, I knew it was something trivial.  Hopefully such questions are tolerated on StackOverflow.  I'll accept your answer in 15 minutes, when I can.  Thanks!

Comment: @WeierstrassSauce sorry to say but no, this is a duplicate question. Duplicated questions are not welcomed on SO.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize the problem was the comparing of the strings.  I would've searched for that if that was the case.

Comment: @WeierstrassSauce if you debugged the program you would have noticed that the problem was in the string comparison to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

`==` operator checks for the equality of Objects rather than the value of the String.

Instead of that, use:

```
if(input.equals("O")){
   //Code here
}
```